# Word Count Algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a good word count class or function. When I copy and paste something from the internet and compare it with my custom word count algorithm and MS Word it is always off by a little more then 10%. I think that is too much . So do you guys know of an accurate word count algorithm in c#.

Comment: Is your algorithm consistently too high or too low?  Or does it vary?

Comment: Are you counting only words, or is what you are pasting also markup.

Comment: Why are you using the MS Word word count as your benchmark for accuracy? Subtle differences in what counts as a "word" can result in significant differences in word count. 10% isn't a surprise there. What you're seeing is probably perfectly accurate, but merely slightly different.

Comment: Have you considered that the MS Word count algorithm might not be that accurate?

Comment: My algorithm is always too high. I am only counting spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String.Split by predefined chars. Use punctuations, spaces (remove multiple space), and any other chars that you determine to be "word splits"

What have you tried?

I did see that the previous user got nailed for links, but here is some examples of using regex, or char matching. Hope it helps, and nobody gets hurt X-)

[String.Split Method (Char[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904305(VS.71).aspx)

[Word counter in C#](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial186_Word-counter-in-Csharp.html)

[C# Word Count](http://dotnetperls.com/word-count)

Comment: not for links, rather, for googling the obvious links w/ no value add  brought in

Comment: @astander Don't forget the _StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries_ option in -_Split_ otherwise, "word1, word2" or "word1? word2" will be counted as 3 words !

Answer (score 8):

As @astander suggests, you can do a String.Split as follows:

```
string[] a = s.Split(
    new char[] { ' ', ',', ';', '.', '!', '"', '(', ')', '?' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

By passing in an array of chars, you can split on multiple word breaks.  Removing empty entries will keep you from counting non-word words.

Comment: This is great, but you should also account for newlines. If you type a word, press enter, type a word, press enter, it will return a count of 0. One of the overloads for Split() allows for an array of strings, so you could change this array to strings of chars and add Environment.Newline (or "\r\n" and \n").

Comment: Unless your input contains very limited formatting, you'll probably need a wider net - consider curly and angled braces, dashes (though this can produce false positives), and other punctuation.

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression to find words (e.g. [\w]+) and just count the matches

```
public static Regex regex = new Regex(
  "[\\w]+",
RegexOptions.Multiline
| RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
| RegexOptions.Compiled
);
```

regex.Match(_someString).Count

Answer (score 1):

You also need to check for `newlines`, `tabs`, and `non-breaking spaces`. I find it best to copy the source text into a **`StringBuilder`** and replace all newlines, tabs, and sentence ending characters with spaces. Then split the string based on spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem in ClipFlair, where I needed to calculate WPM (Words-per-minute) for Movie Captions, so I came up with the following one:

You can define this static extension method in a static class and then add a using clause to the namespace of that static class at any class that needs to use this extension method. The extension method is invoked using s.WordCount(), where s is a string (an identifier [variable/constant] or literal)

```
public static int WordCount(this string s)
{
  int last = s.Length-1;

  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= last; i++)
  {
    if ( char.IsLetterOrDigit(s[i]) &&
         ((i==last) || char.IsWhiteSpace(s[i+1]) || char.IsPunctuation(s[i+1])) )
      count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the stripped down version of c# code class i made for counting words , asian words , charaters etc. This is almost same as Microsoft Word.
I developed the original code for counting words for Microsoft Word documents.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    namespace BL {
    public class WordCount 
    {

    public int NonAsianWordCount { get; set; }
    public int AsianWordCount { get; set; }
    public int TextLineCount { get; set; }
    public int TotalWordCount { get; set; }
    public int CharacterCount { get; set; }
    public int CharacterCountWithSpaces { get; set; }


    //public string Text { get; set; }

    public WordCount(){}

    ~WordCount() {}


    public void GetCountWords(string s)
    {
        #region Regular Expression Collection
        string asianExpression = @"[\u3001-\uFFFF]";
        string englishExpression = @"[\S]+";
        string LineCountExpression = @"[\r]+";
        #endregion


        #region Asian Character
        MatchCollection asiancollection = Regex.Matches(s, asianExpression);

        AsianWordCount = asiancollection.Count; //Asian Character Count

        s = Regex.Replace(s, asianExpression, " ");

        #endregion 


        #region English Characters Count
        MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(s, englishExpression);
        NonAsianWordCount = collection.Count;
        #endregion

        #region Text Lines Count
        MatchCollection Lines = Regex.Matches(s, LineCountExpression);
        TextLineCount = Lines.Count;
        #endregion

        #region Total Character Count

        CharacterCount = AsianWordCount;
        CharacterCountWithSpaces = CharacterCount;

        foreach (Match word in collection)
        {
            CharacterCount += word.Value.Length ;
            CharacterCountWithSpaces += word.Value.Length + 1;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Total Character Count
        TotalWordCount = AsianWordCount + NonAsianWordCount;
        #endregion
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class WordCount
{
    public static int Count(string text)
    {
        int wordCount = 0;
        text = text.Trim();// trim white spaces

        if (text == ""){return 0;} // end if empty text

        foreach (string word in text.Split(' ')) // or use any other char(instead of empty space ' ') that you consider a word splitter 
        wordCount++;
        return wordCount;
    }
}
```