# Counting words from a string builder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string builder which stores many words..for example, i did

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append(reader.Value);
```

now, builder contains string as

```
" india is a great great country and it has many states and territories".. it contains many paragraphs.
```

I want that each word should be unique represented and its word count. example,

```
india: 1
great: 2
country: 1
and: 2
```

Also, this result should be saved in a excel file. But I am not getting the result.

I searched in google, but i am getting it by linq or by writing the words itself. Can you please help me out. I am a beginner.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code that we can look at to help you with?

Comment: NO, I dint got any idea, i have never done, this work also. I googled it, but was unable to get the result.

Comment: I assume whoever upvoted the question read the question as: "How to count words in `StringBuilder` without creating any new strings (except potentially one for each word)?" - which would be an interesting exercise. user2387900 - do you have good reasons to avoid simple `builder.ToString().Split()...` code?

Comment: This is useful link for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633116/word-count-algorithm-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Linq` to achieve it. Try something like this.

```
var result = from word in builder.Split(' ')
             group word by word into g
             select new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

You can also convert this result into Dictionary object like this

```
Dictionary<string, int> output = result.ToDictionary(a => a.Word, a => a.Count);
```

So here each item in output will contains `Word` as Key and it's `Count` as value.

Comment: I think we should consider the situation that the sentence have some punctuations. Such as "_people who write code because they love it it._"   In this case, this method will treat 'it.' and 'it' as two words

Comment: As I commented before, I think before process the string, we should remove the punctuations. Add code `builder = new string(builder.Where<char>(x => !char.IsPunctuation(x)).ToArray());` before process string.

Comment: i don't have enough rep points for this but can someone edit the answer with 4 votes. as far as i know, stringbuilder doesn't have a split method. so it should become builder.toString.Split(' ')

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is one way to get the words:

```
IEnumerable<string> words = builder.ToString().Split(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) function to break up your string into words. You can then use a [`Dictionary<string, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to keep track of unique words and their counts.

You don't really need a `StringBuilder` for this, though - a `StringBuilder` is useful when you contatenate strings together a lot. You only have a single input string here and you won't add to it - you'll split it up.

Once you finish processing all the words in the input string, you can write the code to export the results to Excel. The simplest way to do that is to create a comma-separated text file - search for that phrase and look into using a [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) to save the output. Excel has built-in converters for CSV files.