# Counting the Words in a String

Tags: vb.net

I'm taking an introductory programming class that goes over Visual Basic and I need some help with an assignment if you all would be so kind as to point me in the right direction.  It's sort of a challenge assignment and I'm supposed to figure out how to do these things by myself but I haven't been able to find anything on this.

What I have to do is have a program count the number of words in a string and then print this number.  I've look online to no avail, and I haven't learned how to do anything similar in class.  Any help that you all could offer me would be greatly appreciated.  I know you don't like homework assignments, but I am truly lost on this one.

Comment: String class, Split Method, Array class, Length property. These are the hints to search for

Comment: This question has been asked before. Refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577586/counting-words-from-a-string-builder/16577701#comment23824291_16577701 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633116/word-count-algorithm-in-c-sharp?lq=1

Comment: define word? Is that characters seperated by whitespace or is it more sophisticated? Do you want to count words that appear more than once, what about different spellings of the same word? Do you need to do Natural Langauge Parsing.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point, in VBA at least (and VB has similar functions but I don't know which version you're using), is to use VBA.Split; e.g.

VBA.Split(s, " ") where s is the string to split and " " the delimiter (we're assuming, crudely, that all words are separated by spaces).

This function returns a string array. You can use the UBound and LBound functions to get the size of the array. E.g.

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    Dim arr() As String

    arr = VBA.Split("Hello there", " ")

    Debug.Print UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1

End Sub
```

This will print 2.

Happy coding!

Comment: fine, too bad that poster want to use vb.net

Answer (score 1):

OK, let us say your string is like:

```
string ThisIsYourSentence = "This is some pretty long and annoying sentence, now, isn't it?";
```

You notice that each word is divided from the other by an interval " ". In C# there is a built-in method which do separate strings inside a string, by checking for a special character which divides them:

For your solution you just have to create a new array, which each time when the " " character is met, will fill in with a word.

```
string[] TheseAreYourWords = ThisIsYourSentence.Split(' ');
```

P.S: Oh, sorry, I didn't even see you meant VisualBasic, not C#.

Comment: what about words seperated by `"-"` or by multiple spaces or other combinations of punctuation? +1 for using the right language and heading in the right direction and explaining.

Comment: Well, then you just have to use .Split('-') or whatever symbol the divider is. If you have combinations of symbols, guess you will have to write some a bit more "complicated" checks for each case. P.S: I am really sure there should be a built-in function like .Split in Visual Basic. No point in discovering the boiling water on your own by writing new complicated methods. :P

Comment: The [Split method on a String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is part of .NET and can be used from any .NET enabled language, including C# and VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

you can call a function like this:

```
Public Function CountWords(ByVal value As String) As Integer
    ' Count matches.
    Dim collection As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(value, "\S+")
    Return collection.Count
    End Function
```

or split the given string with space character and get length of array.

Comment: doesn't this just match one or more spaces?

Comment: actually it counts spaces